# Loop over values occuring in every row in Hive table (Hive-QL)

Tags: hive, hiveql

Suppose I have a Hive table named `table` that looks like this:

```
| lower | upper |
|-------|-------|
| 1     | 10    |
| 2     | 3     |
```

Assume that values in `lower` column are strictly less than the corresponding ones in `upper` column. I would like a third column whose value is an aggregate of integers values ranging from the `lower` column to the `upper` column. For concreteness, suppose I want the third column as a sum of all integers between `lower` and `upper`, namely the table

```
| lower | upper | sum |
|-------|-------|-----|
| 1     | 10    | 55  |
| 2     | 3     | 5   |
```

A query in Hive would look like

```
SELECT lower, upper, SUM(...) AS sum FROM table;
```

but I am not able to figure out what the `SUM(...)` would have. I think an appropriate modification of

```
SELECT a, AVG(b) OVER (PARTITION BY c ORDER BY d ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM T;
```

should work but I don't know how to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this way.

I have created a small code in python as sumhive.py

```
sumhive.py-->

import sys
try:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        nums = line.split('\t')
        num1 = int(nums[0])
        num2 = int(nums[1])
        sum=0
        for i in range(num1,num2+1):
            sum=sum+i
        sys.stdout.write('\t'.join([str(num1),str(num2),str(sum)]) + '\n')

except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

change mode for your pyfile:

```
python]$ chmod +x sumhive.py
```

now add this python udf to hive:

```
hive> add FILE /home/xxx/user/vikrant/python/sumhive.py;
Added resources: [/home/xxx/user/vikrant/python/sumhive.py]
```

now below is your table in hive:

```
hive> select * from db.yourhivetable;
OK
1       10
2       5
```

run below query to transform the results using python udf.

```
select TRANSFORM (lower,upper) USING 'python sumhive.py' As (num1,num2,sum) FROM db.yourhivetable;
```

results:

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.56 sec   HDFS Read: 5136 HDFS Write: 15 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 560 msec
OK
1       10      55
2       5       14
Time taken: 14.635 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

**Update: using sql query in hive**

I have used posexplode to get the desired results.

```
hive> select * from db.yourhivetable;
OK
1       10
2       5
```

Below is the query:

```
select t.start_range,t.end_range,sum(t.start_range+pe.i) as seq from
(select lower as start_range,upper as end_range from db.yourhivetable) t
lateral view posexplode(split(space(end_range - start_range),' ')) pe as i,s
group by t.start_range,t.end_range
;
```

here you go!

---

```
    VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 02/02  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 4.04 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK
1       10      55
2       5       14
Time taken: 5.148 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The above question is a prototype of larger computational routine that I originally wrote in Python but for speed would like to implement using `mapreduce` features. Perhaps writing a UDF in Java is the way to go..

Comment: @ Abhishek Parab -- Just now updated answer using sql as well. took some time to made it. :-) It's running perfect and faster than using python udf.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it works! I am a novice in Hive and don't know about `LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE` but will try and understand your code. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sum_n(
l int , u int 
);


insert into sum_n values (1,10),(2,3),(2,5),(3,7);
select l,u,case
when u-l=1 then u+l
when u-l>1 and l=1 then (u*u+u)/2
when u-l > 1 and l <> 1 then (u * u + u)/2 - (l * l - l)/2
else null
end as summ
from sum_n;

l       u       summ
1       10      55.0
2       3       5.0
2       5       14.0
3       7       25.0
```